# Comparisons involving literals safe?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, precision, literals

Consider the code:

```
#define LITERAL 1.0

int main()
{
    double x = LITERAL;

    if (x == LITERAL) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Is this guaranteed to return `1` for any numerical double value we set `LITERAL` (not just `1.0` but any other double literal)?

EDIT: Why was the question closed because of "missing details"? It is a well defined C/C++ question and got a very good answer. There are no more details required, it is a general question about how these languages work.

Comment: Choose C or C++.

Comment: Does your question just involve `double` or is that just an example, and you would like an answer for `float` as well?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am interested in an answer for both languages (if there is a difference regarding this particular case), that's why I added both to the tags intentionally.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Float as well, if that behaves differently than double.

Comment: Not if `LITERAL` can be `long double` type (ex. `#define LITERAL 0.1l`) and `long double` has greater range/precision than `double`.

Comment: @EOF: The question states `LITERAL` is set to a “double literal”.

Comment: If you use c++,  generally you shouldn't use #define, 

Prefer 
`const float LITERAL = 1.0;`

Comment: In general, should never use a `==` comparison with floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to assume an implementation that's (attempting to be) conforming to Annex F, since otherwise all bets are off; without Annex F (IEEE floating point) C allows all floating point results to be arbitrarily bogus.

Then, according to the language spec, depending on your C implementation's definition of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, yes or no.

If the value is 0 or 1, then yes. The literal is interpreted as `double`, and the `double` object stores that value faithfully, and the equality operator yields 1 (true), reflecting that.

If the value is 2, then only if the literal is the eact decimal representation of a representable `double` or is expressed with sufficient precision that it differs from one only past the precision of `long double`. Otherwise (for example if it's something like `0.1`), since the literal is interpreted with *excess precision* in `long double` format the initialization/assignment to a `double` object truncates the precision to the nominal `double` precision. Then the equality comparison is guaranteed to result in 0 (false). You can [see this in action on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dWpwrS) (note: remove the `volatile` and you can see it optimized to return a constant 0).

To make matters more complicated, GCC does this **wrong by default** unless you use `-std=c..` or `-fexcess-precision=standard`, and **always does it wrong** in C++ mode, and clang/LLVM always do it wrong. So on a target with excess precision (32-bit x86 or m68k, the only real-world-relevant targets with `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` not 0 or 1) horrible things happen. For a peek into how bad they get, see [GCC issue 93806](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93806) and (recursively) all of the "See Also" related issues.

So for practical purposes, yes, for everything but 32-bit x86 and m68k, and in a correct C implementation no (but maybe yes, because your compiler is probably broken) for them.

Comment: I don't think the following is trrue: "Then the equality comparison is guaranteed to result in 0 (false)." If the literal is not exactly representable in `double` *and* not exectly representable in `long double`, *and* the closest representable `long double` is also exactly representable as `double`, then the comparison returns `1`, contrary to your claim.

Comment: Is it really the case that the literal `0.1` can be interpreted in `long double` format? I thought that is only the case if we use the `L` suffix?

Comment: @user3137490: If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 2, not only *can* it be interpreted in `long double` precision; it **must be**.

Comment: @EOF: I think you're probably right, but that's not going to arise in practice without **a lot** of decimal places. Do you have a suggested wording to make it more precise?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I'd say it's entirely doable. `long double` typically has ~21 decimal digits worth of precision, so a string constructed like "`1.`concat`21*'0'`concat`1`" or so should round to `1` in both `double` and `long double`. Anyway, I'd say "Then the equality comparison may result in 0 (false)."

Comment: Since you provided a godbolt, so do I: https://godbolt.org/z/FpVwHf

Comment: @EOF: Nice. You can see the code change by adding/removing zeros. :-)